# How to force using GroupAggregates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, grouping

I have the following table `tbl`:

```
id    user_id      amount
PK    integer     integer
```

I also created the index on `user_id` as

```
CREATE INDEX idx_fk_user_id
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (user_id);
```

Now explain the execution plan for

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT SUM(amount) s
FROM tbl
GROUP BY user_id
```

which returned me

```
 "HashAggregate  (cost=117903.97..117905.14 rows=118 width=9) (actual time=1869.591..1869.623 rows=207 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..101439.31 rows=3292931 width=9) (actual time=0.017..501.316 rows=3292931 loops=1)"
```

As far as I understand, [HashAggregates](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/postgresql/operations) uses large amount of memory. So, I presume it would be mnore efficient to use GroupAggregates instead. The table's used mostly for reading (All data's written by a scheduler task once a day).

How can I apply `GroupAggregates` here instead of `HashAggregates`?

Comment: The question is why do you want to "apply" `GroupAggregate"? If the planner chose to use a `HashAggregate` then apparently there is enough memory available and because it thinks it's the most efficient thing to do. The amount of memory usable by such an operation is determined by the `work_mem` setting. If you reduce that, you might see the `GroupAggregate` but I doubt your query will get faster.

Answer (score 1):

You understand, that [changing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html) settings require different values on different machines for different tables, right? So I played with my table and here my effective values:

```
set seq_page_cost = 8;
set enable_hashagg to false;
```

First forces usage of index (my table is small and CPU are weak, and SSD is fast) by making IO scan more expensive.

Second does what you wanted.

So after setting SESSION valiable I have plan:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=11.66..12.68 rows=45 width=8) (actual time=0.152..0.309 rows=45 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=11.66..11.85 rows=76 width=8) (actual time=0.139..0.155 rows=76 loops=1)
        Sort Key: index_i
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
        ->  Index Only Scan using index_i on table_t  (cost=0.14..9.28 rows=76 width=8) (actual time=0.021..0.055 rows=76 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 0
Total runtime: 0.380 ms
```

**Update:** 
at your [link](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-group-by) there is an advise

> For PostgreSQL, you must add an order by clause to make an index with
>   NULLS LAST sorting usable for a pipelined group by.

It did not help alone...